# Программа выдаёт ошибку

Tags: c++

Написал простейший алгоритм на с++, который находит сумму элементов массива, которые не равны максимальному, повторяющие максимальные элементы в сумму так же не должны входить. Только проблема, проходит 9 из 10 тестов, 4 тест выдаёт ошибку выполнения. Пытался проверять, запускать программу с разными числами, но ошибки не выдаёт. В чём может быть проблема ?

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, SAME = 0, sum = 0;
    cin >> n;   
    int* mass = new int[n];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cin >> mass[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (mass[j] < mass[j + 1]) swap(mass[j], mass[j + 1]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (mass[1] == mass[i+1]) SAME++;
    }
    for (int i = SAME+2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        sum += mass[i];
    }
    cout << sum;
}
```

Comment: У вас массив меньше, чем нужно? Или циклы больше, чем нужно?

Answer (score 2):

```
int* mass = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

И во всех остальных циклах - тоже.